# umake doesn't list Java IDE's

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, ide, ubuntu-make

Clarifying a [bad question which I'm closing](https://askubuntu.com/q/872252/45156), why doesn't netbeans, or even Eclipse, show as an IDE option for umake?

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ umake --version
16.02.1
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ umake ide netbeans
usage: umake ide [-h] {lighttable,visual-studio-code} ...
umake ide: error: argument framework: invalid choice: 'netbeans' (choose from 'lighttable', 'visual-studio-code')
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ umake ide lighttable
Choose installation path: /home/thufir/.local/share/umake/ide/lighttable
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04 LTS"
thufir@doge:~$
```

Only one Java:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ sudo update-alternatives --verbose --config java
There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java
Nothing to configure.
thufir@doge:~$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to update your umake version

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
sudo apt-get update
```

Then, installing Ubuntu Make:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
```

you should get 16.11.1 version

Comment: pls confirm that's the right ppa for xenial.  why not webupd8?  are they different?

Comment: I do not know what is in webupd8, but this one is in wiki https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make

Comment: I wasn't able to get NB to start, the GUI never showed up.  Further reading indicates that might be that I'm using JDK 9.  Any thoughts?  I'll switch to JDK 8 if it persists after this installs.  Oracle JDK through webupd8.

Comment: just uninstall and umake should install you all dependencies, including java

Comment: Installing `oracle-java8-set-default` and `oracle-java8-installer` fixed it.  I think those come from webupd8 as I recall, system wide.  Would've liked to try JDK 9, but, meh.  Thanks for the help :)