# NetBeans doesn't work

Tags: java, 18.04, netbeans

I never used Ubuntu in my life before, and now I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 lts. I have problem with NetBeans. Although I have JDK and the rest that needs, I get this:

[image: ]]

I can't open or start a project,nothing happens when I click. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: What's your java version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Installing Netbeans 9.0:**

- **Building from Source:**

  1. Download the source zip from [here](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/incubator/netbeans/incubating-netbeans-java/incubating-9.0/incubating-netbeans-java-9.0-source.zip) and extract. Or open terminal and clone the repositories from GitHub using

     ```
     git clone https://github.com/apache/incubator-netbeans
     ```
  2. Install either Oracle JDK or OpenJDK.

     - For Oracle JDK: Download JDK8 from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk10-downloads-4416644.html) and run these commands:

       ```
       sudo su
       mkdir /opt/jdk
       tar -zxf jdk-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt/jdk
       update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_181/bin/java 100
       update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_181/bin/java 100
       ```
     - For OpenJDK, run

       ```
       sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
       sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre
       ```
  3. Install Apache ANT: For installing Apache Ant v1.10.3, run

     ```
     sudo apt install ant
     ```
  4. Once you’re all set just enter the incubator-netbeans directory and type `ant` to build the Apache NetBeans IDE.
  5. Once built, the IDE bits are placed in the `./nbbuild/netbeans` directory. You can run the IDE from within the incubator-netbeans directory by typing `./nbbuild/netbeans/bin/netbeans` or use `ant tryme` to run the Apache NetBeans IDE.
- **Installing from Binaries:** Download the binary zip from [here](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/incubator/netbeans/incubating-netbeans-java/incubating-9.0/incubating-netbeans-java-9.0-bin.zip). Unpack the zip and run `netbeans` in bin folder using `./netbeans`. I'll suggest to make a `desktop entry` a.k.a. menu shortcut. For details about it read [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/66918/816190) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/64237/816190).

### For natively installing Netbeans v8.2, See [Karel's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1045101/816190).

### **Original Answer:**

Java seems to be quite broken currently under 18.04. This can create problems with Netbeans as well as Eclipse. So, I'll suggest not to install Java from Ubuntu's repository.

If you want JDK as well as Netbeans first of all remove Java completely from your system. Then download NB+JDK from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-netbeans-jsp-3413139-esa.html).

I assume that downloaded files go to `Downloads` and downloaded file name is `jdk-8u111-nb-8_2-linux-x64.sh`. Use below commands to install Netbeans and JDK 1.8.

- Navigate to the folder(Downloads) containing file using

  ```
  cd ~/Downloads
  ```
- Make file executable(if already not) using

  ```
  chmod +x jdk-8u111-nb-8_2-linux-x64.sh
  ```
- Finally run it using

  ```
  ./jdk-8u111-nb-8_2-linux-x64.sh
  ```
- Follow on screen instructions to complete installation.

Comment: The link NetBeans + JDK Bundle in your answer is obsolete, and it has been updated to this new link: http://netbeans.apache.org/. A lot of stuff has changed. NetBeans has been updated to version 9.0 and it isn't bundled with JDK anymore. It's probably worthwhile updating this answer in order to get a source at Ask Ubuntu for information about how to install NetBeans 9.0. Alternatively I've already solved the problem of how to install NetBeans 8.2 natively in Ubuntu 18.04: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045090/java-problem-with-eclipse-and-netbeans/1045101#1045101.

Comment: That's a good idea.

Comment: If you post, I'll comment if I see it, or you can PM me in [Raiders of the Lost Downboat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3877/raiders-of-the-lost-downboat) chatroom and I'll post an explanatory comment to slow down the undecided close voters.