# Java IDEs not working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, ide, intellij

I am not able to run or create any Java projects in Ubuntu 18.04 using Eclipse, NetBeans or IntelliJ Idea.

Results of `which java` :

```
Oracle java SE
```

Results of `java -version` :

```
java 8
```

Comment: java SE and java 8

Comment: Your Java path is buggered up because you installed Oracle Java SE. Your IDEs will recognize Java automatically if you uninstall Oracle JavaSE and install openjdk-8-jdk from the default Ubuntu 18.04 repos. This is how to install Eclipse and NetBeans in Ubuntu 18.04: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045090/java-problem-with-eclipse-and-netbeans/1045101#1045101. The eclipse snap package also automatically recognizes the latest Java version in 18.04, default-jdk because it's more up-to-date than the eclipse apt package.