# NetBeans isn't opening on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, java, jdk, netbeans

I'm a new Ubuntu Linux user and I thought to start learning java with this new environment. I started to install java and NetBeans by searching google, java installed but not NetBeans. I searched more but none work for me.

Before posting this, I also searched in ask ubuntu and found some solutions about this but sorry to say, none work for me. Netbeans 8.2 just doesn't start on ubuntu 18.04. I installed java version `1.8.0_181`. With this, I also tried installing java 10 but also failed here as NetBeans 8.2 doesn't support 10. So what can I do?

And I want another suggestion, that is, Java is updated and its current version is jdk10; which version I should go for learning? 8 or 10? What should I do, I am totally confused.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java problem with eclipse and netbeans](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045090/java-problem-with-eclipse-and-netbeans)

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans requires Java 8 to run. It's doesn't support Java 10 at the moment. As for your second question, I'd start with Java 8 also.

EDIT: Installation procedures

Add ppa repo

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

SRC: [Launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java)

This is supposed to work for 18.04 and 18.10

Download Netbeans 8.2 installer. It's a bash shell script ending in .sh. Make sure it has executable permissions.

Navigate to your Netbeans installer download folder and open a console and type:

```
./netbeans-8.2-linux.sh
```

SRC: [Netbeans.org](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/82/install.html#install_windows)

Follow the onscreen prompts for the installation. Refer to the appropriate links I've provided should you have any troubles.

Comment: With Java 8, netbeans isn't running on my machine. I mentioned that in the post. It just doesn't start.

Comment: Are you using OpenJDK or OracleJDK? I use NetBeans 8.2 on my PC with OracleJDK 8. And I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS too...

Comment: I tried both. :(

Can you show me the way you installed all of these? It'll be a great help.

Comment: Be glad to. Give me a few to put it together. I'll update my answer with the details.

Comment: Answer updated with installation details. Hopefully this will get you up and running!