# Problem with opening NetBeans

Tags: netbeans

I'm new to Linux. I have Ubuntu 18.04 and I tried installing NetBeans. At first, it was opening telling me that it couldn't find JDK something like that so I went to netbeans.conf file and edited the netbeans_jdkhome. After doing that NetBeans doesn't open. It just loads at the beginning and after that nothing. What should I set to that netbeans_jdkhome variable to make NetBeans open correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Please revert those changes first!

Comment: How? I'm really new to Linux and struggling to find my way around

Comment: One linux's rule of thumb is always make a backup, you need to reverse those changes so Netbeans will launch, then we can guide you on how to fix that jdk home issue. Worst you may have to reinstall!

Comment: And how do I reverse them?

Comment: Undo what you did if you don't remember then you will have to install fresh!

Comment: I'm uninstalling it but still nothing. Generally there's a second NetBeans that I had installed and can't uninstall it completely and that probably messes things up. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Netbeans?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75549/how-do-i-install-netbeans)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java problem with eclipse and netbeans](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045090/java-problem-with-eclipse-and-netbeans)