# Ubuntu 16.04 32-bit - How to upgrade netbeans-8.0.2 to netbeans-8.2?

Tags: 16.04, netbeans

I've installed netbeans-8.0.2 on an ubuntu 16.04 32-bit (GNOME Flashback Metacity).

```
/home/name/NetBeansProjects
/home/name/netbeans-8.0.2
```

Is it possible and how to upgrade netbeans-8.0.2 -> netbeans-8.2 ?

Comment: Both links don't address my issue. I asked if it is possible to upgrade netbeans on a ubuntu 16.04 32-bit

Answer (score 0):

- The recommended way to upgrade to NetBeans 8.2 is with the following commands:

  ```
  sudo apt update          
  sudo apt upgrade  
  sudo apt install ubuntu-make # it's compatible with 16.04 32-bit  
  umake ide netbeans
  ```

  These commands will install NetBeans 8.2 which is compatible with openjdk-8-jdk.
- To start the NetBeans IDE Plugin Installer open NetBeans and from the menu bar select *Help* -> *Check for Updates*. This will offer updates to multiple NetBeans plugins including plugins for JavaScript, HTML5 Kit and Node.js Project Support.

  [image]

The version of NetBeans from the default Ubuntu repositories is 10.0 in Ubuntu 18.04 and later.

Comment: I just ran the recommended command ... but when running Help -> Check for Updates I get 'Your IDE is up to date! There are no updates available.' What am I missing?

Comment: But the window header still stays NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 ... and I don't see any new plugins like HTML5/JavaScript

Comment: When I run 'sudo apt install ubuntu-make' again I get 'ubuntu-make is already the newest version (16.02.1).'

Comment: And when I run 'umake ide netbeans' again ... I get

usage: umake ide [-h] {visual-studio-code} ...
umake ide: error: argument framework: invalid choice: 'netbeans' (choose from 'visual-studio-code')

Comment: When I opened my NetBeans 8.2 and selected *Help* -> *Check for Updates* it showed me a long list of updates including for updates to the plugins for JavaScript, HTML5 Kit and Node.js Project Support which are installed by default in NetBeans 8.2. Run the command `umake ide -h` and you will find that *netbeans* is shown in the results.

Comment: I still only see netbeans-8.0.2

Comment: Run the command  `umake ide -h` and you will find that *netbeans* is shown in the results.  It's the third IDE in the list after *arduino* and *atom*. That's not netbeans-8.0.2, it's the latest version of NetBeans.

Comment: If I run umake ide -h ... I get usage: umake ide [-h] {visual-studio-code} ...

positional arguments:
  {visual-studio-code}
    visual-studio-code  Visual Studio focused on modern web and cloud

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit

Comment: Your error message is so weird, it's as if you ran either `umake --help ide` or `umake -h ide` instead of `umake ide -h` . It should at least show you a list of IDEs that umake is able to install. You can also get Oracle NetBeans 8.2 bundles at: https://netbeans.org/downloads/. With your luck that will probably go wrong too.

Comment: I update umake https://askubuntu.com/questions/872282/umake-doesnt-list-java-ides ... now it works. What's the recommended installation path? It suggests: '/home/name/.local/share/umake/ide/netbeans' . Previously it was installed under /home/name/netbeans-8.0.2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81064/discussion-between-karel-and-philipp-m).